# combining two separate arrays into one array with objects

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two separate arrays which looks something like this

```
var x = ['one', 'two', 'three'];
var y = ['1', '2', '3'];
```

I am doing this to combine them

```
var newArray = [];
for (var i = 0; i < x.length && i < y.length; i++) {
    newArray[i] = [x[i], y[i]];
}
```

desired output

```
newArray = [
    ['one', '1'],
    ['two', '2'],
    ['three', '3']
]
```

This is my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/sghoush1/EjRPS/4/

Comment: @thanks david..I think you caught it before I did. Thanks for the correction

Comment: Looking at the console, your desired output seems to be what you get. And, for the edit, you're quite welcome. =)

Comment: i think your code is working

Comment: Your fiddle is working perfectly fine. What's the problem, how do you think the output differs?

Comment: Ha..I swear I saw undefined for five times before I ended up posting this question. Yeah it is working. I guess this was a false alarm. Sorry guys. I guess there was no question to begin with :/

Comment: If you're looking for a good name for this, many libraries call this functionality `zip`.

Comment: @ScottSauyet because that's the name this function had in traditional functional programming languages, e.g. LISP.

Comment: @Alnitak: Yes, but if the OP is having difficulty implementing it (or proving that it was implemented correctly!), that might be more information than desired!  :-)

Answer (score 3):

On ES5 you can use [`Array.prototype.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to simplify your loop:

```
var newArray = x.map(function(n, i) {
    return [n, y[i]];
});
```

See the above link for a shim for older browsers.

If you have [Underscore.js](http://underscorejs.org/#zip), you can use:

```
var newArray = _.zip(x, y);
```